# Not sure of model choice - significant p-values but very low R2 adj

Tags: data-transformation, count-data, fitting, misspecification

I am writing a thesis in which I'm trying to see what the relationship is between how innovative a patent is (as determined by a series of measures based on NLP that) and the financial value of that patent (as determined by a different measure, in millions of dollars).

My dataset contains around 2 million US patents.

I'm basing my work on:

The text-based innovation measures developed by my professor (with NLP, count data).

E.g. new_word counts how many times the focal patent used a word that was not found in all patents published prior to the focal patent. New_word_reuse counts the number of subsequent patents that reused the new word introduced by the focal patent.

A financial value developed by a different researcher (continous, in millions of dollars).

By linking these two I now have a dataset with 11 text-based innovation measures (count data), 2 financial value measures (one in real dollars deflated by CPI, one in nominal value) and a variable containing the number of times each patent has been cited in different patents (cites, also count).

My training is not in statistics (though I did follow a two Stats courses in the past two years) so I'm having some trouble finding the correct model/fit. All other regressions I've done in the past were simple OLS regressions with relatively little data transformation needed.

The dataset I'm working with now is something else. Many of the variables have a high number of patents with 0 as values. Nearly all of them are quite skewed.

I've tried many different types of regression, and I keep getting significant parameters yet an extremely low R2 (I'm assuming because of the large sample size). I'm not sure what my next steps are to diagnose the issues and find a correct specification.

I've added [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GTNG.jpg) of summary statistics for all variables and a picture of a regression with all variables included (just to show everything) and one where I left out some variables that were insignificant or heavily correlated to other variables.

I probably made a lot of newbie mistakes so apologies, I'm trying to catch up to all the stats I used to have.

Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a case of a model that reliably explains very little